# How to include aws cognito authentication in a google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, amazon-cognito

From Google Sheet's App Script, we are trying to access our database using authentication via aws-cognito-identity. I am having trouble even getting started because I am not sure how to import modules because this is not a node.js environment. Does anybody have experience doing this and would not mind sharing it?
Thanks

Comment: [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%28+%5Bamazon-*%5D+%29+%5Bhmac%5D)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got this to work:

```
var authEndpoint = "https://[put your auth domain here].amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token";
var authClientId = "[put your Cognito client ID here]";
var authSecret = "[put your Cognito auth secret string here]";
var authExpirationTime = undefined;
var authLatestToken = undefined;

function getAuthToken() {
  // If last known token is still valid, use it.
  if (authLatestToken && authExpirationTime && authExpirationTime < new Date().getTime()) {
    return authLatestToken;
  }

  // Otherwise, request new token from AWS Cognito
  var params = {
    method: "POST",
    followRedirects: true,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(authClientId + ":" + authSecret)
    },
    payload: "grant_type=client_credentials"
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(authEndpoint, params);

  // Verify response
  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Authentication failed: HTTP Response not OK.");
  }
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  if (!data.access_token) {
    throw new Error("Authentication failed: No token returned.");
  }

  // Set internal vars and return token
  authLatestToken = data.access_token;
  if (data.expires_in > 0) {
    authExpirationTime = new Date().getTime() + data.expires_in * 1000;
  }
  return authLatestToken;
}
```

Then you can add an authorization header with this bearer to any requests that need to be authenticated, for example:

```
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + getAuthToken()
    },
```